# While installing elasticsearch it doesnt give error but downloading does not proceed beyond this?

Tags: elasticsearch

I downloaded the zip file from electic.co then unzip it and in cmd ran elasticsearch.bat.  Something gets loaded but don't go beyond the below lines, please help me I am beginner in elk.

```
[2022-06-29T15:10:38,307][INFO ][o.e.i.g.DatabaseNodeService] [DESKTOP-I8UJC56] successfully loaded geoip database file [GeoLite2-Country.mmdb]
[2022-06-29T15:10:38,339][INFO ][o.e.i.g.DatabaseNodeService] [DESKTOP-I8UJC56] successfully loaded geoip database file [GeoLite2-ASN.mmdb]
[2022-06-29T15:10:39,061][INFO ][o.e.i.g.DatabaseNodeService] [DESKTOP-I8UJC56] successfully loaded geoip database file [GeoLite2-City.mmdb]
```